# dispatch an action after api call in redux-saga if some error occurs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

Hi guys i was using redux saga in my project but i am stuck in part where i have to dispatch an action whenever an error occurs and then update the state in errorReducer

Here is my code
So as soon as user clicks on signup function we have the following code to run

```
function* signup(action) {
  yield put({ type: TOGGLE_LOADING, payload: true });
  yield call(userSignup, action.payload);
  yield put({ type: TOGGLE_LOADING, payload: false });
}
```

then we have function userSignup() running

```
const userSignup = async (userData) => {
  try {
    console.log("api hittinh");
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_HEADER_URL}/api/signup`, {
      data: userData,
    });
    console.log({ response });
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("in catch");
    console.log(err.response.data);
    yield put({ type: ERROR, payload: err.response.data });
  }
};
```

now as user tries to sign up with the email which already exists, i send status code of 409 'Unauthorized' and then it goes to catch statement, now how can i dispatch an action over here ?

I cant use yield here cause, it can be used inside generator function and neither can i use ''useDispatch' cause it says

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
> function component

Answer (score 0):

yield command can be used only generator functions(function*).
And you need to catch error in saga function.

```js
function* signup(action) {
  try {
    put({ type: TOGGLE_LOADING, payload: true });
    const response = yield call(userSignup, action.payload);
    yield put({ type: TOGGLE_LOADING, payload: false });    
  } catch (err) {
    yield put({ type: ERROR, payload: err.response.data});
  }
}

const userSignup = async (userData) => {
  try {
    console.log("api hittinh");
    const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_HEADER_URL}/api/signup`, {
      data: userData,
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: You don't need the try/catch block in your solution just to re-throw the error, so I would remove it. I would also move ` yield put({ type: TOGGLE_LOADING, payload: false });` to a `finally` block, so it would be called when there's an error as well.